# Canvas кнопка меню

Tags: javascript, svg, анимация, canvas

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста: какая технология используется для реализации кнопки меню как на сайте https://www.panoply.co.uk/? Заказчик просит скопировать..
Вижу что canvas, но не могу понять в ручную ли написан код или может фреймворк какой.. Заранее благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/YzzyxxZ

Answer (score 10):

Вот собрал вам нечто похожее из подручных средств, в этом примере нет WebGL, все посчитано и нарисовано через 2d контекст.

```js
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let k = 300, a1 = 0, a2 = 0, dir = 0, far = 300, 
    w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height, planes = [];

ctx.translate(w/2, h/2);

for (var i=-20; i<21; i+=20) {
    addRect(10,10,20,i,-20)
    addRect(10,10,-20,i,-20)
    addDiag(15,10,20,i,-20)
    addDiag(-15,10,20,i,-20)
}
addTopDiag(25,15,-25,20)
addTopDiag(-25,-15,-25,20)

function addTopDiag(x1,x2,dy,dz) {
    whitePlane([
        pt(-x1, dy, -dz),
        pt(-x2, dy, -dz),
        pt(x1, dy, dz),
        pt(x2, dy, dz)
    ]);  
}

function addDiag(w, h, dx=0, dy=0, dz=0){    
    whitePlane([
        pt(0, h/2+dy, -5),
        pt(0, -h/2+dy, -5),
        pt(w, -h/2+dy, dz),
        pt(w, h/2+dy, dz)
    ]);
}

function addRect(w, h, dx=0, dy=0, dz=0){    
    whitePlane([
        pt(-w/2+dx, -h/2+dy, dz),
        pt(-w/2+dx, h/2+dy, dz),
        pt(w/2+dx, h/2+dy, dz),
        pt(w/2+dx, -h/2+dy,dz)
    ]);
}
    
requestAnimationFrame(render)

function whitePlane(points){
    planes.push({color: 'white', points});
}

function pt(x,y,z) {
    return {x, y, z};
}

function project(p) {
  let sinA1 = Math.sin(a1), cosA1 = Math.cos(a1);
  let sinA2 = Math.sin(a2), cosA2 = Math.cos(a2);
  let x = p.x*cosA1 + p.z*sinA1;
  let z = p.z*cosA1 - p.x*sinA1;
  let y = p.y*cosA2 +   z*sinA2;
  let kd = k/(z*cosA2 - p.y*sinA2 + far);
  p.X = kd*x;
  p.Y = kd*y;
}

function render() {
  a2 += dir * 0.1;
  if (a2 < -Math.PI/2 || a2 > 0) {
    dir = 0;
    a2 = a2 > 0 ? 0 : -Math.PI/2;  
  } 
  if (a2 < 0 && a2 > -Math.PI/2)
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  planes.forEach(plane => plane.points.forEach(project));   
  ctx.clearRect(-w/2, -h/2, w, h);
  planes.forEach(drawPlane);
}

function drawPlane(plane) {
    ctx.fillStyle = plane.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(plane.points[0].X, plane.points[0].Y);
    for (var i = 1; i < plane.points.length; i++)
        ctx.lineTo(plane.points[i].X, plane.points[i].Y);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function toggle() {
  if (a2 < 0 && a2 > -Math.PI/2)
    return;
  dir = a2 === 0 ? -1 : 1
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/22/700/200);
}

canvas {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=90 height=90 onclick="toggle()" ></canvas>
```

Answer (score 6):

В отличие от соседнего ответа, посчитал почти все точки по формуле и нарисовал при помощи SVG...

```js
let cos = Math.cos, sin = Math.sin, 
    k = 1000, a1 = 0, a2 = 0, far = 1000, 
    dir = 0, planes = [];

let pts = Array(8).fill(0).map((e, i) => {
  let a = Math.PI*(.25+.5*Math.floor(i/2)) + (i%2?.2:-.2);
  return [cos(a)*30, sin(a)*30];
});

let t = -25;
whitePlane([pt(0,t),pt(1,t),pt(4,t),pt(5,t)])
whitePlane([pt(2,t),pt(3,t),pt(6,t),pt(7,t)])
for (var i=0; i<3;i++){
    let t2 = t+20*i;
    let t3 = -15+20*i;
    whitePlane([
        pt(4,t2),pt(5,t2),{x:0,y:t2,z:-7},pt(6,t2),pt(7,t2),
        pt(7,t3),pt(6,t3),{x:0,y:t3,z:-7},pt(5,t3),pt(4,t3),
    ])
}
    
requestAnimationFrame(render)

function whitePlane(points) {
 let id = "plane_" + planes.length;
 svg.innerHTML += `<polygon id="${id}" ></polygon>`;
 planes.push({points, id});
}

function pt(i, y=0) {
    return {x:pts[i][0], y, z:pts[i][1]};
}

function project(p) {
  let x = p.x*cos(a1) + p.z*sin(a1);
  let z = p.z*cos(a1) - p.x*sin(a1);
  let y = p.y*cos(a2) +   z*sin(a2);
  let d =   z*cos(a2) - p.y*sin(a2) + far;
  return [ (k/d)*x ,(k/d)*y ];
}

function render() {
  a2 += dir * 0.1
  if (a2 < -Math.PI/2 || a2 > 0){
    dir = 0;
    a2 = a2 > 0 ? 0 : -Math.PI/2;  
  } 
  dir !== 0 && requestAnimationFrame(render)
  planes.forEach(plane => window[plane.id]
       .setAttribute("points", plane.points.map(project)));   
}

function toggle() {
  if (dir !== 0)
    return;
  requestAnimationFrame(render);  
  dir = a2 === 0 ? -1 : 1
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

polygon {
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<svg id=svg onclick=toggle() viewbox="-50 -50 100 100"></svg>
```

Comment: (+1) Крайние линии у бургера волнистые изначально. Это так задумано? А так-то эффектно выглядит!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT это проекция так работает, перспектива же =), если картинку сделать маленькой то это не заметно =), подкрутил цифры, теперь не видно

Comment: видно, но чуть-чуть. Если не видел бы предыдущего варианта, то не заметил бы :) В общем, Молодец

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ну конечно, полностью от него не избавиться, перспектива все-таки ;)